Is every Jewish woman's ambition to be the mother of the Messiah?
On the (primarily Christian) Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, an answer to the question "Luke 1:28 favored vs highly favored" claimed that:

And that is, it was every Jewish women’s ambition to be the ‘mother’ of the Messiah.

Is this true?
Possible duplicate: Was there a tradition that Jewish girls desired to be the mother of the messiah? (where the answer seems to be resoundingly no, this is not the case), but that question specified "the historical time period of the 1st century AD or earlier", while I am interested in the answer in any time period, up to and including today.

If that was a true ambition of every woman, it would find its place in women's prayers. I do not find such a prayer in any of the books of women's prayers. Aliza Lavie (editor) "A Jewish Woman's Prayer Book" or Norman Tarnor "A book of Jewish Women's Prayers. Translations from Yiddish

This sounds like it was lifted from a joke about every Jewish mother treating her son like he's God.

@rosends I've heard that joke but I promise that wasn't where I got this idea from!

This is about the equivalent of asking if it's every American mother's ambition to be the mother of the President, and the answer is the same: In most cases, mothers don't think along those lines at all, but I'm sure some mothers somewhere probably hope for this.

That site is filled with bizarre misinformation and conclusions.

@Fred I can only say that the reason I asked about this here is because the original claim seemed somewhat dubious.

Can I ask why this was closed as off-topic?  I'm not disputing that, but I'd like to know so I can avoid asking bad questions in the future.

Not at all. According to the Bible, the future messiah will be a descendant of King David, so the vast majority of women who are not married to one of his descendants know they have no shot.
There is a tradition that there was a prophecy that the Jews would have a great leader named Samuel, so many women named their son Samuel in hopes that he would be that Samuel. But Samuel was never a messiah (literally "annointed one"), rather he anointed Saul and then David.

Accepted on the basis that "According to the Bible, the future messiah will be a descendant of King David", which seems to immediately disprove the original claim.  Thank you.

This ignores the fact that the vast majority of Jews today do not know they are not a descendant of King David. cc @מרים

@DoubleAA Are you suggesting that many Jewish women today don't know their lineage but do hope they're the mother of the Messiah?

Anyone married to a Kohen or Levite knows their husband is not of the Davidic line.

Ever-so-slightly related -- there's a fascinating comment in the Talmud about the power-jockeying between King David's wives. Each of them prayed that their son be deserving of the throne. But Batsheva's prayer about Solomon was that he merit to Divine inspiration. (Which, as we see from Moses' sharp remarks to Joshua, is not zero-sum. There can only be one king at a time, but lots of people can have Divine inspiration.)

I was once at a Bris where the family were kohanim; one family member remarked that they hoped this child would grow up to be the Kohen Gadol in the speedily [but not too speedily?] rebuilt Temple.

@מרים Are you suggesting that many Jewish women today don't know their lineage but do hope they're the mother of the Messiah? No, he is merely suggesting that the reasoning provided in this answer doesn't refute that possibility.

It's not that she desires it, it's that she "knows" that he has the potential to be. She believes in him.
